# Excel VBA: Set Specific Picture Color

Tags: excel, vba, colors, image

Have tried recording a macro to get me on the way here, but am not having any luck.

I have a picture and want to use the preset colors to recolor it.

I want a macro that does the effect of Picture -> Color -> Recolor.

The only luck I've had is something along the following syntax:

```
Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureAutomatic
```

The Googles suggest there are only 5 members we can use here, so there is no way to programmatically access some of the presets you see in the menu referenced above (e.g. the Red Accent color Dark 2 preset).

Transparent Background and Transparent Color don't really work because the icon in use has a white matte background as-is.

Anybody had any luck with this in the past?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have you looked into ForeColor.RGB and BackColor.RGB? Or if the ColorType has worked for you you can try setting the type to `msoColorTypeRGB`

Comment: That sounds promising, but I am having a hard time making the syntax work.  Any help?  If I wanted RGB value of (255, 0, 0), how would I set it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set img= Plan.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Picture.png", msoFalse, msoCTrue, POSITION X,POSITION Y, width, HEIGHT)
Imagem.PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureWatermark
```

Add image and config with types office code ... maybe if you modify can work